# Compression and destination_format in API call for Bigquery extract_table?

Tags: python-2.7, google-bigquery

I am using bigquery_client.extract_table(dest_table_ref, destination) to extract my queried data into a destination_table and thereafter to a GCS bucket location.

[Link for compression and destination_format](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.extract.destinationFormat)

Below is my code  for extract:

```
job = bigquery_client.extract_table(dest_table_ref, GCS_bucket_file_destination)
job.result()  # Waits for job to complete
```

Is there anyway to pass compression and destination_format here in extract_table method?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `job_config` input for these definitions, something like:

```
from google.cloud.bigquery import ExtractJobConfig

extract_conf = ExtractJobConfig()
extract_conf.compression = 'GZIP'
extract_conf.destination_format = 'CSV'

job = bigquery_client.extract_table(dest_table_ref,
                                    GCS_bucket_file_destination,
                                    job_config=extract_conf)
result = job.result()  # Waits for job to complete
```

Comment: Yeah I am already using job_config_1 = bigquery.QueryJobConfig() and setting values like job_config.destinatio,job_config.use_legacy_sql and so on.. but I QueryJobConfig doesn't have compression and format parameters , So how can I pass two different method to job_config .. will it be like job_config = {extract_conf, job_config_1 }

Comment: not quite sure what you mean. One job is for querying and the other is for extraction, they are not the same so each have its own config definition.